# Load and store image profile in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm developing my first App and I need some help with the registration process because at the moment, when a user "clicks" on the REGISTER button I create a new row in my SQL database but I also would like to store an image (that means store it in the database and also in my folder FTP) in order to show that image in his ProfileViewController.

Can you explain me exactly to process to achieve that? I need some examples or a good tutorial to follow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert you Image to NSData this way:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
// or
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image);
```

More information about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)

then you can just store the data as byte stream. I recommend to use CoreData for this task.

Some tutorials:

[Core Data Tutorial for iOS: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

[Core Data Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQmY97-qj9w)

Comment: Thanks dit. Can you show an example or a tutorial to follow? I really appreciate your help. Regards.

Comment: I'm also interested in having an example for this because I also need to know that. At the moment I have a selectPicture function and the image is stored in the var called "imageView". How can I proceed from that to store the image with UIImageJPEGRepresentation? Thanks.